# Problem with Eventlocator Method for NDSolve

Tags: programming, numerics, differential-equations, numerical-integration

I want to solve the ode and plot the solution `v[x]` for different values of parameter `a` where `x=2000` (for just any fixed position x or event at x). By looking at examples  of `EventLocator` available online i tried to write the code as:

```
data = Table[Reap[
    soln = 
     NDSolve[{I D[v[x], x] == (0.4 + a)*v[x], v[0] == 1}, {v[x]}, {x, 0, 2000},
      Method -> {"EventLocator", 
        "Event"          -> Abs[v[x]]^2, 
        "EventCondition" -> x == 1000,
        "EventAction"    :> Sow[{a, Evaluate[Abs[v[x]]]^2 /. soln}]}]][[2, 1]],
  {a, -1, 0, 0.3}]
```

But it does not give data file i wanted to grab as`{a,[Abs[v[x]]^2}`. instead it shows:

> Part::partw: Part 1 of {} does not exist. >>
>   Part::partw: Part 1 of {} does not exist. >>
>   Part::partw: Part 1 of {} does not exist. >>
>   General::stop: Further output of Part::partw will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
>
> {{{{v[x]->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,2000.}},<>][x]}},{}}[[2,1]],
>    {{{v[x]->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,2000.}},<>][x]}},{}}[[2,1]],
>    {{{v[x]->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,2000.}},<>][x]}},{}}[[2,1]],
>    {{{v[x]->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,2000.}},<>][x]}},{}}[[2,1]]}

Any kind of help or suggestion will great .Even if you can help using other method like using for loop and logical condition that will be great too.

Comment: I think you don't need the `soln` bits. This will work 

`data = Table[
  Reap[NDSolve[{I D[v[x], x] == (0.4 + a)*v[x], 
     v[0] == 1}, {v[x]}, {x, 0, 2000}, 
    Method -> {"EventLocator", "Event" -> Abs[v[x]]^2, 
      "EventCondition" -> x == 2000, 
      "EventAction" :> Sow[{a, Abs[v[x]]^2}]}]], {a, -1, 0, 0.3}]`

You don't get any points because `Abs[v[x]]` is never zero.

Comment: I tried that but did not work. Thanks.

Comment: Could you specify what does not work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can do it more simply :

```
xvalue = 1000;
avalues = Range[-1, 0, 0.3];
results = Table[NDSolve[{I D[v[x], x] == (0.4 + a)*v[x], v[0] == 1}, 
 v[x], {x, 0, 2000}][[1, 1, 2]] /. x -> xvalue, {a, avalues}]

(* {-0.999044 + 0.0441925 I, -0.0221014 - 0.999765 I, 1. + 0. I, -0.0221014 + 0.999765 I} *)
```

[image: solution]

Comment: Its working! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Do you have a BRG ordered screen?

Comment: @Szabolcs I'm sorry but I don't know what it is.

Comment: I mean, are the coloured pixels in your screen arranged as blue-green-red instead of the more usual [red-green-blue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Pixel_geometry_01_Pengo.jpg)?  On my red-green-blue screen the fonts in your plot look very fuzzy with colour fringing, as if the [subpixel antialiasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_antialiasing) assumed a BRG ordering.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for the explanation - I don't know, how can I tell ? I didn't change any such settings on purpose.

Comment: @b.gatessucks I have another question. After closing the NDSolve[] you used [[1,1,2]]. Would you kindly explain the use of those numbers? I understand for two numbers it would be row column but plz tell me what happens when 3 or more :-s

Comment: @Mush More generally than row/column, which applies to 2 dimensional lists, `[[...]]` (shorthand for [Part](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html?q=Part&lang=en)) applies to lists of any dimensions. In my case `[[1,1,2]]` extracts the `InterpolationFunction` solution to the equation so I can calculate its value at the point of interest.

Comment: Yes i understood that but i just wanted to learn how to use that. For example why did you assign the last number 2? Sorry if i am bothering you too much :( @b.gatessucks

Comment: @Mush The solution is in the the form 

example = {{v[x] -> InterpolationFunction[...]}};

example[[1]] = {v[x] -> InterpolationFunction[...]};
example[[1,1]] = v[x] -> InterpolationFunction[...];
example[[1,1,2]] =  InterpolationFunction[...];